# lpSolve - how to define constraint with discrete values

Tags: r, lpsolve

Is there any way to define constraint for lpSolve as a set of discrete values.
E.g., I can define constraint with '<=','=','>=':

```
    fn.obj <- c(3.62, 5.19, 7.29, 7.76, 3.82, 4.86, 4.03, 8.81, 9.14)
    require(lpSolveAPI)
    ...
    add.constraint(model, c(70,70,-30,70,-30,-30,-30,-30,70), ">=", 0)
    ...
```

What if I just want my x[1],x[2],...,x[9] each to be in a discrete set of values like:

```
    x[1] in c(20000,25000,30000,35000,40000,45000,50000)
    ...
```

Comment: There's no such option in LPSolve, but since your values are equally distant, you can define (for each x) a new integer variable z1, and 2 other constraints:  `x1 = z1 * 5000; 4 <= z1 <= 10` (of course you can also simply define x1 as integer in [4-10] and multiply by 1/5000 constant wherever you use x1)

Comment: Thank you, @digEmAll. Is there any way to add these new constraint without adding 9 more variables into my model?

Comment: please post a small but complete model example (not just some lines as in your question) and I will try to modify it and explain how to do that ;)